# Receive Memory Warning In ASIHTTPRequest to Upload Multiple images in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to upload multiple images in iOS7, i am getting memory warning when upload the large size(4MB each) images.i am convert the all the images in base64 encoding and uplaod that base64 data on the server.

here is my code:

```
-(void)UploadImages:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictdata
{
            NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“here is url ”];
            NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strURL];
            ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

           for (int i = 0; i < [dicData count] ; i++) {

                NSString *strKey = [[dicData allKeys] objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString *strValue = [dicData objectForKey:strKey];
                [request setPostValue:strValue forKey:strKey];
            }
           [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
 [request setUploadProgressDelegate:appDelegate.progressIndicator];
                [request setUploadProgressDelegate:delegate];
                [request  setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:YES];
                request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;

                request.showAccurateProgress = TRUE;
                [request setDelegate:delegate];
                [appDelegate.request setTimeOutSeconds:60000];
               request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;

              [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
            [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
            [request startAsynchronous];


}
```

Comment: maybe you should upload piece by piece

Comment: how can i upload piece by piece

Comment: How many times [dicData count] is called?

Comment: one time only it contain the imagebase64data and imagekey

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is a a really old framework, if it possible is better if move to something newer, such as MKNewtworkkit or AFNetworking. As said by Siverchen the problem most probably is that you are encoding all the images to create the body in the for loop.

Comment: Try @autoreleasepool in for loop to release memory

Comment: first if the image count is big, you should not encode all, you can try encode one and upload it, after uploading you can encode another, just do this on by one. secondary, if each image is big enough you should try another method such as read the image by stream and upload it  instead of load the whole image to the memory , normally the first method should work.

Comment: nmh thanks for help using @autoreleasepool in for loop its works for me. so thanks again last three days i am facing this problem and using yr trick it works awesome.